# How to format BigDecimal to ALWAYS have two decimal places?

Tags: java, number-formatting, bigdecimal

This:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.00)
```

becomes `0.0`

I want it to be `0.00`

What is the correct format pattern for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the String constructor: `new BigDecimal("0.00")`.  Using `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` completely destroys any formatting you used to input the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
value = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING)
```